# Different Connections to Different Database by checking Map size

Tags: java, database, multithreading

I have a HashMap that look something like this-

```
 HashMap<String, TableConnectionInfo> tableList
```

which means it's value is a Class `TableConnectionInfo` which looks something like this-

```
public class TableConnectionInfo {

    public String url;
    public String user;
    public String password;
    public String driver;
    public String suffix;
    public String sql;

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    public void setDriver(String driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public String getSuffix() {
        return suffix;
    }

    public void setSuffix(String suffix) {
        this.suffix = suffix;
    }

    public String getSql() {
        return sql;
    }

    public void setSql(String sql) {
        this.sql = sql;
    }

}
```

So Suppose, If I have two values in the above `HashMap`. That means, I need to make two different connections to two different database. And suppose if that map has three values, then I need to make three different connections to three different database.

In the main thread, I am populating the above map by reading it from the properties file like this and after that this map won't get modified.

```
for (String arg : databaseNames) {

    TableConnectionInfo ci = new TableConnectionInfo();

    String url = prop.getProperty(arg + ".url");
    String user = prop.getProperty(arg + ".user");
    String password = prop.getProperty(arg + ".password");
    String driver = prop.getProperty(arg + ".driver");
    String suffix = prop.getProperty(arg + ".suffix");
    String sql = prop.getProperty(arg + ".sql");

    ci.setUrl(url);
    ci.setDriver(driver);
    ci.setPassword(password);
    ci.setSql(sql);
    ci.setSuffix(suffix);
    ci.setUser(user);
    tableList.put(arg, ci);
}
```

Now I am passing this `tableList` map to various threads like this and it won't be modified (by making set calls) by any thread. Each thread will be using get method to get the required method.

```
for (int i = 0; i< 1000; i++) {
    service.submit(new Task(tableList));
}
```

So in the run method I need to make different conenctions basis on the `tableList` size. So if `tableList` size is two, that means I need to make two different connections, callableStatements and methods to two different database.

**Question:-**

So is there any better way as compared to way I am doing in my `run method` to create different connections to database basis on `tableList size` ?

Below is my Task class that impelements Runnable Interface

```
class Task implements Runnable {

    private Connection[] dbConnection = null;
    private CallableStatement[] callableStatement = null;
    private ArrayList<Method> methods[] = null;

    private final HashMap<String, TableConnectionInfo> tableLists;

    public Task(HashMap<String, TableConnectionInfo> tableList) {
        this.tableLists = tableList;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {

            int j = 0;
            dbConnection = new Connection[tableLists.size()];
            callableStatement = new CallableStatement[tableLists.size()];
            methods = new ArrayList[tableLists.size()];

            for (TableConnectionInfo ci : tableLists.values()) {

                dbConnection[j] = getDBConnection(ci.getUrl(), ci.getUser(), ci.getPassword(),  ci.getDriver());
                callableStatement[j] = dbConnection[j].prepareCall(ci.getSql());

                methods[j] = getRequiredMethods(ci.getSuffix());
                j++;
            }

          }
             }
       }
```

Make a connection to that database-

```
private Connection getDBConnection(String url, String username, String password, String driver) {

        Connection dbConnection = null;

        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        } 

        return dbConnection;
    }
```

Just to add here `getRequiredMethods` will get all the methodNames of a particular table. So suppose if tableList size is 1 then we will be having only one connection to that database so `getRequiredMethods` will get all the methods for that `table1` and store it in a ArrayList. But suppose if tableList size is 2 then we will be having two different connections to two different database so that is the reason I made methods as an array so that it can hold methods for table 1 and methods for table 2.

Comment: You could make the TableConnectionInfo the key to the Map (after implementing hashCode in TableConnectionInfo), and the value of the Map would be the methods retrieved from the database.  Then there's no confusion about where the Methods came from.

Comment: I'd also possibly have each thread working with only one TableConnectionInfo.  What's above isn't really multithreading...it's adding a single Runnable that sequentially goes through the TableConnectionInfo objects.  If your runnable took a single TableConnecitonInfo and returned the methods, it wouldn't need to know about the Map.  Then the controlling code can use a threadPoolExecutor, handing out the TableConnectionInfo objects when required and putting the method into the map when the threads complete.

Comment: But the problem is, we have different methods for different tables. Some tables has 10 methods and some table has 20 methods.

Comment: Could you have the logic used to extract the methods in separate Java classes.  Then when the TableConnectionInfo object is created, it has one of the objects which is responsible for retrieving the methods.  It just then depends on how the tableConnectionInfo object is created.  The logic used to extract the methods from the table is encapsulated away from the logic retrieving it.

Comment: Almost like TableConnectionInfo.getMethods(), which is called by the thread.  It doesn't know or care how the methods are populated, or how many.  Just that it returns a Collection of Method (or String, or whatever it's meant to return about the Method).

Comment: Thanks EdH for the suggestions. I was able to understand few things but not all of them. Is it possible for you to provide some examples basis on my code. So that I can understand more. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's kind of hard to provide examples, when I'm not really sure what you're after.  Is this meant to return arrays of Connections, Statements and Methods?

Comment: Yes it will return Arrays of Connections, statements and methods. And after getting those suppose I have two tables. Each of my thread will be running for 1000 times. So it will start inserting into two tables using those connections, statements and methods 1000 times. Like, each thread will write one by one data in both the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm still not sure how the Task is meant to use the data it's getting.  But, I would move the getConnection, getCallableStatement and getMethods() functions to methods on the TableConnectionInfo.  You can simply create a Collection of TableConnectionInfo (initialised as you already have, storing in an ArrayList).  Then the Runnable simply iterates through the TableConnectionInfo.

```
public class TableConnectionInfo {

    private String url;
    private String user;
    private String password;
    private String driver;
    private String suffix;
    private String sql;

private Connection connection;

<snip... getters and setters for the properties>

public Connection getConnection() {
    // TODO  create and return a connection
    if (connection == null) {
        // create the connection
    }
    return connection;
}

public CallableStatement getCallableStatement() {
    // get the callable statement
    return null;
}

public Collection<Method> getMethods() {
    // Get the Methods
    return null;
}

}

public class TableTask implements Runnable {

private Collection<TableConnectionInfo> tables;

public TableTask(Collection<TableConnectionInfo> tables) {
    this.tables = tables;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    for (TableConnectionInfo table : tables) {
        // do something with table.getConnection(), or table.getCallableStatement()
        // and/or table.getMethods()
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks EdH. But with this approach how it is going to make sure this connection is for this table? And these methods are for this table?

Comment: I don't know.  Could the table (or tables) be defined in the TableConnectionInfo?  I'm not sure where the tables are defined in the original code.  So clearly I'm not understanding the issue you're trying to achieve.  Sorry. :/